# differences in the XML returned in a DVWP vs list.asmx webservice for a plain text field with a URL

Tags: web-services, custom-list, xslt, data-view-web-part, xml

I'm trying to figure out why the XML returned in a DVWP is different then what is returned with the list.asmx webservice for a plain text field with a URL in it.

I have a list with a plain text field. I have an item and the value for the field is "http://www.google.com".

In the DVWP the value of `@PlainTextField` is `<a href='http://www.google.com'>http://www.google.com</a>`.

In the list.asmx webservice the value of `@ows_PlainTextField` is `http://www.google.com`.

Why is the DVWP returning the field with the HTML markup for the link?

Answer (score 0):

List service is returning the raw data. And this is the same data that is stored in SharePoint.

Data View Web part on the other hand applies Transformations on the data. This is done using XSLT.

Comment: This is before I apply any transformations. I'm dumping the raw XML at the very start and the XML shows the value with the markup. `<Row ... PlainTextField="<a href='...'>...</a>" .. />`